# Random number,with nonuniform distributed

Tags: java, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generate random number with non-uniform density](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908811/generate-random-number-with-non-uniform-density)

I try to identify/create a function ( in Java ) that give me a nonuniform distributed sequence of number.
if I has a function that say `function f(x), and x>0` it will give me a random number
from `0` to `x`.

**The function most work with any given `x` and this below is only a example how I want to have.**

But if we say `x=100` the function `f(x)` will return s nonunifrom distributed.

And I want for example say

`0 to 20` be approximately 20% of all case.

`21 to 50` be approximately 50% of all case.

`51 to 70` be approximately 20% of all case.

`71 to 100`be approximately 10 of all case.

In short somting that give me a number like normal distribution and it peek at 30-40 in this case `x` is `100`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

( I can use a uniform random gen as score if need, and only a function that will transfrom the uniform result to a non-uniform result. )

**EDIT**

My final solution for this problem is:

```
/**
 * Return a value from [0,1] and mean as 0.3, It give 10% of it is lower
 * then 0.1. 5% is higher then 0.8 and 30% is in rang 0.25 to 0.45
 *
 * @return
 */
public double nextMyGaussian() {
    double d = -1000;
    while (d < -1.5) {
        // RANDOMis Java's normal Random() class.
        // The nextGaussian is normal give a value from -5 to +5?
        d = RANDOM.nextGaussian() * 1.5;
    }
    if (d > 3.5d) {
        return 1;
    }
    return ((d + 1.5) / 5);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you just write a function that sums a number of random numbers it the 1-X range and takes an average? this will tend to the normal distribution as n increases

See:

[Generate random numbers following a normal distribution in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325472/generate-random-numbers-following-a-normal-distribution-in-c-c)

I hacked something like the below:

```
class CrudeDistribution {

    final int TRIALS = 20;

    public int getAverageFromDistribution(int upperLimit) {
        return getAverageOfRandomTrials(TRIALS, upperLimit);
    }

    private int getAverageOfRandomTrials(int trials, int upperLimit) {
        double d = 0.0;
        for (int i=0; i<trials; i++) {
            d +=getRandom(upperLimit);
        }
        return (int) (d /= trials);
    }

    private int getRandom(int upperLimit) {
        return (int) (Math.random()*upperLimit)+1;
    }
}
```

There are libraries in Commons-Math that can generate distributions based on means and standard deviations (that measure the spread). and in the link some algorithms that do this.

Probably a fun hour of so of hunting to find the relevant 2 liner:

https://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/distribution.html

Comment: there is Math.nextGaussian() but this uses a standard deviation and could generate an unlimitedly large number requiring bucketing.

Comment: Why is `CrudeDistribution` and `TRIALS` package scope?

Comment: I think this is the post that is most close to a good solution here. 
`Steve Kuo` Tt do not matter, is probably not a pure java code for that matter.

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution would be to generate a first random number between 0 and 9.

0 means the 10 first percents, 1 the ten following percents, etc.

So if you get 0 or 1, you generate a second random number between 0 and 20. If you get 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6, you generate a second random number between 21 and 50, etc.

Comment: Yes, but sorry, I think this not is a good way, base on my `x` can be all value from zero to a big number.

Comment: Well, replace `between 0 and 20` by `between 0 and x / 5`, and you have the same result.

Comment: Good point, this perhaps work, but I hops to use a mathematical function and not logic function.

Comment: You probably won't find one.  +1.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to do a random number between 1-100 and based on the result do another random number in the appropriate range.

1-20 -> 0-20

21-70 -> 21-50

71-90 -> 51-70

91-100 -> 71-100

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It might make sense if you explain how it satisfies the requirements.  It's not at all clear just from this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the f(x) first.

Assuming values x are equiprobable, your f(x) is

```
double f(x){
if(x<=20){
 return x;
}else if (x>20 && x<=70){
 return (x-20)/50*30+20;
} else if(...
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

Just generate a bunch, say at least 30, uniform random numbers between 0 and x. Then take the mean of those. The mean will, following the central limit theorem, be a random number from a normal distribution centered around x/2.